# How to execute MSSQL stored procedure and take a result in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to execute Microsoft SQLServer stored procedure and take a result in GORM. Return List of model or list or map.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Key point:

```
db.Raw("call findBetween(?, ?)", min, max).Scan(&products)
```

full file sample

```golang
package models

import (
    "config"
    "entities"
)

type ProductModel struct {
}

func (productModel ProductModel) FindProductsByPrices(min, max float64) ([]entities.Product, error) {
    db, err := config.GetDB()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        var products []entities.Product
        db.Raw("call findBetween(?, ?)", min, max).Scan(&products)
        return products, nil
    }
}
```

See https://learningprogramming.net/golang/gorm/call-stored-procedure-with-parameters-in-gorm/

A note for connection string: Your `main.go` will like this

```golang
package postgres

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlserver"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code  string
    Price uint
}

func Main() {
    dsn := "sqlserver://sa:12345678@localhost:1433?database=gorm"
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    // Migrate the schema.
    db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
    // Create.
    db.Create(&Product{Code: "D42", Price: 100})
    // Read.
    var product Product
    db.First(&product, 1)                 // Find product with integer primary key.
    db.First(&product, "code = ?", "D42") // Find product with code D42.
    // Update - update product's price to 200.
    db.Model(&product).Update("Price", 200)
    // Update - update multiple fields.
    db.Model(&product).Updates(Product{Price: 200, Code: "F42"}) // non-zero fields.
    db.Model(&product).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"Price": 200, "Code": "F42"})
    // Delete - delete product.
    db.Delete(&product, 1)
}
```

```
for "sqlserver://sa:12345678@localhost:1433?database=gorm"

sqlserver:// : means use Microsoft SQL Server database
sa : your db server name
123456 : your db password
localhost:1443 : db ip and port
database=xxx : use database xxx
```